# Does subscribing to a large collection pass all the data to the client?

Tags: meteor

I have a search function and currently what I'm doing is, subscribe to my collection each time the search parameters change like this :

```
 Meteor.subscribe('job_search', searchParams).ready();
```

My question is, do we really have to do this? When fetching the data I use the search params. Will subscribing to all the data at once load all the data and reduce the performance of the app?

Comment: Can't you subscribe all the required data you need for the first time and search from it the next you want to search ?

Comment: Also checkout easy search, it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscription itself doesn't fetch the data, but it can act as a filter. The helper does the fetching whenever the data changes or a reactive query parameter changes. As long as your helper query doesn't fetch all the data you should be ok.